# Use createDocumentFragment() to add a table row

Tags: ajax, dom

**UPDATE** -- this is a complete rewrite of the question on Monday 11/26

---

This code works:

```
name_this_table = "station_list"+i;
station_table = document.getElementById(name_this_table);

for (station_index in station_detail)
{
    newRow = station_table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].insertRow(-1);

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode("one"));

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode("two"));
    newRow = null;
}
```

But I want to use `createDocumentFragment()`, like this:

```
name_this_table = "station_list"+i;
station_table = document.getElementById(name_this_table);  // NOTE 1
//station_table = document.getElementById(name_this_table).tBodies[0];

var tableFrag;
tableFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
tableFrag.appendChild(station_table);  // NOTE 2

for (station_index in station_detail)
{
    newRow = station_table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].insertRow(-1); // NOTE 3
  //newRow = tableFrag.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].insertRow(-1);
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode("one"));

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode("two"));
    newRow = null;
}        
document.getElementById(name_this_table).appendChild(tableFrag);
```

I have various failures to report -- not run-time errors, but the rendering stops.

- NOTE 1 (above) -- I have tried the line below (uses `tbodies`) as an
  alternative.
- NOTE 2 -- If I uncomment this line, the rendering stops
  at that point.
- NOTE 3 -- Here I am trying to use the tableFrag ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### NEW ANSWER posted Tuesday 11/27

After a lot of experimenting, this works.  I'd love any feedback (for one thing, I'm not sure I'm seeing a performance gain.

```
name_this_table = "station_list"+i;
station_table = document.getElementById(name_this_table);  

var tableFrag;
tableFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
tableFrag.appendChild(station_table);  // NOTE 2

for (station_index in station_detail)
{
    station_id = station_detail[station_index]["station_id"];
    var newRow;
    newRow = document.createDocumentFragment();
    newRow = station_table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].insertRow(-1);

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode("one"));

    ...

    station_table.appendChild(newRow);
    newRow = null;
}
```